# Cast a column in CodeIgniter for PostgreSQL query

Tags: sql, codeigniter, postgresql

I'm using CodeIgniter to build an application with PostgreSQL as the database layer.

I have an AJAX based search function in the application that queries multiple columns in the database for potential matches. One particular column has a type of BIGINT. In order to do a LIKE query on this column, I first need to cast it to text. Writing the SQL for this is straightforward:

```
 SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE columnname::text LIKE '1011%';
```

At the moment I cannot see a way of replicating this using CodeIgniter's Active Record as the following produces an error:

```
$this->db->like('columnname::text', '1011%');
```

Is it safe to assume that it's not possible to do this type of query in CI and should revert to `$this->db->query();`?

The error I receive from CI is:

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number:
ERROR: column "columnname::text" does not exist LINE 3: WHERE "columnname::text" LIKE '%'
```

I haven't left the error number out above, that is how it appears.

Comment: what is the error you getting with this?

Comment: I've added the error message to the question @Nil'z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to confirm that it is indeed the case that using the `query` method was needed.

```
$sql = ('SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE columname::text LIKE ?');
$query = $this->db->query($sql, array($str . '%'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried without the **::text** like that:

```
$this->db->like('columnname', '1011%');
```

Usually you don't need to specify the datatype, unless inside specific functions or particular cases

Comment: Yes. Sorry I should have specified that I discovered the fact that I needed to cast by doing that exact line of code. It produces another error complaining about trying to use LIKE on a BIGINT field type.